# How to exclude (drop) cell values that are numbers in a character column

Tags: r, subset

I have a large data set with one column that includes both characters (i.e. "A", "B", etc) and numbers, but the numbers are read-in and assumed to be characters as well. I want to get rid of all rows where the cell for this column is a number. For simplicity, I will show just a mock vector representing the issue I am having with the column.

For example,

```
data<-c("A","A","B","B","1","2","-2")
```

This is data I inherited and a large data set - is there a good way to parse out/drop the cells with the numbers 1,2,-2 which are read-in as characters?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work with my dummy data. Would you mind explaining what the "^-?" and "+$" do, so I can keep learning R?

Comment: On my real data set, to check if grepl worked as hoped, I used levels(data$Col) but it still shows the numbers in the levels. Is there a better way to check rather than using the levels command?

Comment: You could convert it to `character` column and check the `unique(data$Col)` or use `data <- droplevels(data)` after you subset the dataset and then check `levels(data$Col)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple option would be:

```
data <- droplevels(data[is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data$col))), ])
```

Convert the column (col) to numeric and subset those values that turned to NA (which means that they are not numbers). Then, drop factor levels that are no longer in use.

Some example usages:

```
v1 <- c('A12', 'AB12', '-2.53', '25.29', 'BCd')
v1[is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(v1)))]
#[1] "A12"  "AB12" "BCd"
```

Or with special characters:

```
v1 <- c('A_12', 'AB12', '-2.53', '25.29', 'B-Cd')
v1[is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(v1)))]
#[1] "A_12" "AB12" "B-Cd"
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple `regex` option is below.  Here, I am subsetting the dataset using `grepl` by removing those elements that have numbers starting from beginning (`^`) to end (`$`) of the string.

```
subdat <- droplevels(data[!grepl('^[0-9.-]+$', data$yourCol),])
```

Visualization

```
^[0-9.-]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tsQcOqmapUL89LPT)

If the column is `factor`, you can use `droplevels` to drop the levels or can use `factor` again to drop the "unused" levels.  Then, check "yourCol" of "data" by `levels(data$yourCol)`.  Another option is to convert to "character" column by `data$yourCol <- as.character(data$yourCol)` and use `unique(data$yourCol)`

Testing with some example data

```
 v1 <- c('A12', 'AB12', '-2.53', '25.29', 'BCd', '-12AB5', '-AB125', '- ')
 v1[!grepl('^[0-9.-]+$', v1)]
 #[1] "A12"    "AB12"   "BCd"    "-12AB5" "-AB125" "- "
```

Doublechecking with @docendodiscimus code

```
 v1[is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(v1)))]
 #[1] "A12"    "AB12"   "BCd"    "-12AB5" "-AB125" "- "
```

NOTE: I did update the `regex` after finding that the initial one may not work in some cases.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer. Much appreciated!